# Change of Elder Wand ownership

Tags: harry-potter, the-cursed-child

During the events of *Cursed Child* Harry was disarmed by Delphini in the church of Godric's Hollow.

Does this mean that the Elder Wand has changed its ownership to Delphini?

Comment: Related, not duplicate: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/139808/51379

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Maybe, but if so not for long

If Harry was still master of the Elder Wand, it would almost certainly have transferred its loyalty to Delphini. The latter did disarm Harry:

> HARRY: Fine. I’ll deal with you alone.
>
> *He moves to attack her again. But she is far stronger. HARRY’s wand
>   ascends upwards towards her. He is disarmed. He is helpless.*
>
> <sub>*Harry Potter and the Cursed Child*</sub>

**However, we cannot be sure that Harry is still the master of the Elder Wand.** He’s been an active Auror for over a decade. It is entirely possible that someone else disarmed him in the interim, without killing him, and that he never disarmed that individual again (or disarmed someone who disarmed that individual, or disarmed someone who disarmed someone who disarmed that individual, or....)

What’s more, **Delphi was defeated after she disarmed Harry.**
 Now, she did not have her wand, because Cedric had disarmed her:

> *Bang. DELPHI’s wand is pulled away from her. SCORPIUS looks on in astonishment.*
>
> <sub>*Harry Potter and the Cursed Child*</sub>

After that she went straight to the past. And indeed, she is a very powerful witch: she casts all her spells wandlessly in her battle with Harry.

> DELPHI: Father . . .
>
> *She tries to get a glimpse of his face again — there is almost a dance happening here.*
>
> You are not Lord Voldemort.
>
> DELPHI unleashes a bolt **from her hand.** HARRY matches her.
>
> <sub>*Harry Potter and the Cursed Child*</sub>

So she could not have been disarmed. But she *was* defeated in magical combat. There’s no doubt that the Elder Wand would have seen this as making the person who defeated her the stronger witch or wizard:

> HARRY: I’ve never fought alone, you see. And I never will.
>
> *And HERMIONE, RON, GINNY, and DRACO emerge from the doors, and fire up their spells at DELPHI, who screams out in exasperation. This is
>   titanic. But she can’t fight them all.*
>   *There are a series of bangs — and then, overwhelmed, DELPHI tumbles to the floor.*
>
> DELPHI: No . . . No . . .
>
> HERMIONE: Brachiabindo!
>
> *She’s bound.*
>   *HARRY advances towards DELPHI. He doesn’t take his eyes off her. All the others stay back.*
>
> <sub>*Harry Potter and the Cursed Child*</sub>

Now, it’s not clear whom the Elder Wand would have considered to have defeated her, though Hermione seems the likeliest contender. But whoever that individual may be, ***they* would then be the master of the Elder Wand, not Delphi.**

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the above answer, but we have to consider the most horrible and confusing of concepts aswell - time.

Think about it - the characters go back to 1981. Now,  I don't know whether it would make any difference, but in 1981 Harry was not the master of the elder wand, Dumbledore was still. I'm not sure of when adult Harry travels back, his claim to mastery of the elder wand would be temporarily revoked, because in a linear  sense the events of Deathly Hallows are yet to happen, and surely there couldn't be two wizards in one time period who can lay claim
as the wand's master. There can only be one master of the elder wandZ

However on his personal timeline , those events have happened so I don't know which one would be followed. If thepersonal timelike was fine followed,  then Delphi followed by Hermione would be the wand's master

Comment: I struggle to follow your reasoning, could you make it a bit clearer and possibly use canonical information?

Comment: There must be sources from the play you can quote to support your answer. I myself struggle to follow your logic, it's possible other readers may too.

Comment: I don't see how in this instance there can be any more canonical information - we are talking about the concept of time here, a tricky subject that can bend and twist. As the person above writes, Delphi defeats Harry back in 1981, followed by the entire cast defeating Delphi afterwards. Now, if we assume that the events that lead to Harry's ownership of the wand have already taken place, but think about the year they are in - 1981. Technically, how can Harry be the Elder Wand's master when it's 1981? This is where the linear timeline and the personal timeline theories come into play.

Comment: The linear timeline (that follows time chronologically)  would state that Harry was not elder wand's master st this point, because in 1981 it belonged to Dumbledore. Even though adult Harry had had the events happen to him,  It's common sense there is no sources needed, only your brain. This whole thread is based on fan theory, does the hserabove need to quote sources about wand allegiance

Comment: The user above quotes part of the script to support his answer. Answers with support from the work they're derived from are better received and usually get more attention. I was merely trying to help. You can learn more from our [tour](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tour)

Comment: Then if you flip it, you have the personal concept of a timeline, where the events that led to Harry's ownership of the wand have already happened to the Harry that goes back in time, hence even in 1981 he would be the elder wand's master.. Have you ever seen movies with time travel? People go back in time and have events happen to them, yet it's chronologically paradoxical. Yet it still happens. We do not know whether time is a straight tangent or if it can be bent an twisted.

Comment: Whether or  or they quoted part of the script, they're still only theorising. We do not know for sure whether the elder wand has changed allegiance at all. They're speculating just as I am. I'm not going to go through every physicist's theses on time and space just to add my two cents to a theory. I personally agree with the original statement^, I was just adding that in 1981, Dumbledore was chronologically the elder wand's master. If Harry goes back to 1981, that would mean there were two masters of the elder wand in 1981- how can that possibly be when there can only be one master at any time